# GIT Client on Windows Complaining about Ownership

Tags: windows, git, raspberry-pi, git-extensions

With great difficulty due to my limited knowledge of Linux, I set up a GIT server on my Raspberry Pi. It works great except for one thing that's been driving me nuts. I've used every Google fu move I can think of and I've gotten nowhere.

I'm using Git Extensions as the client on 3 Windows machines. One at work (no problems) and 2 at home. The local repository at home is on a shared NAS drive on my LAN. It works fine on my main computer, but when I try to access it on my secondary computer, I get the following error:

warning: '//NAS/REPOSITORY' is owned by:
'S-1-5-...'
but the current user is:
'S-1-5-...'

where 'S-1-5-...' is two different really long alphanumeric strings that mean nothing to me. It says warning, but then whenever I try to do anything I immediately I get errors I can't decipher after that like:
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
or
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.

I'm the only user, using the same windows account, username, email address, etc. configured in Git Extensions. As I understand it on the server end, the only user is git which I use for all machines.

As a workaround, I'm able to clone the repository to a different folder on my secondary computer and I have no problems with GIT, but I have problems with my code because it expects things to be in a certain directory. I can change that based on the user, but as far as my code knows, I am the same user on both machines (because I am!). So that is not a good solution. I want to be able to work in the same folder on my NAS no matter what computer I'm using.

-Is there a way to configure GIT or GIT Extensions (I'm not totally sure who is doing the complaining) to not care about ownership? I've tried cloning as a Public Repository, but I guess that doesn't mean what it seems to mean because I get the same errors.
-How do I know and/or configure what user GIT or GIT Extensions thinks I am?

Comment: Those long ugly strings are Windows UUIDs (Windows calls them "SIDs"): they identify a user, universally across all Windows systems (or at least they purport to do so). This is a Windows OS-level concept, not something Git controls; Git just uses it (specifically on Windows only) to see who owns some file or folder.

Comment: Meanwhile, the message `fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree` suggests that you're trying to work directly off a *bare* repository on the NAS drive. This is not the way to work with Git. You should *clone* the bare repository on the NAS drive, into a *local* repository on your own machine, and work with that local repository. This is a bit of a pain if you switch from one machine to another as Git requires that each machine have **its own** local repository, so you end up with three different Git repositories.

Comment: Given the rest of your question, it sounds like this software and Git have fundamentally different views of How Things Work. To use Git *and* this other software *together* you will have to compromise: work locally with Git, and have some additional *deployment* system that installs the one you've just been working on. It's either that, or don't use Git. The deployment system acts as a bridge between the two views (Git's, "everything is local, you work here on your own machine" vs this software's "everything is global, you work from afar").